# What's the best way to remotely configure a running asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, configuration

I have an ASP.NET web application that I'm deploying and I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage which environment it should point to when it starts up and to make sure that I haven't overlooked any options.

First a little bit of background.

The application is web deployed automatically from a build server, using the artifacts generated by the continuous build. The deployment package contains the configuration settings for every available environment, so you end up with something like this:

```
/Config/Environments/Development.xml
/Config/Environments/UAT.xml
/Config/Environments/Production.xml
```

The question is, what's the best way to indicate to the application when it starts which environment configuration file it should load?

Ideally I'd like to be able to change the current environment of the running application if possible, but I'm happy to skip this for now as I can always do a redeploy if need be.

I'd also like to avoid changing any of the artifacts that are created by the build, especially because the web deploy package is a zip file and doing that would mean rebuilding the web deploy package.

I've come up with the following options:

1. Use an environment variable on the target machine to hint at what environment to start up with and, if not present, default to development. The main downside to this is that I wouldn't be able to run two instances of the application on the same machine that point to different environments, and because we typically deploy uat and staging environments to the same machine this might become a problem.
2. Remotely edit the web.config indicating which environment to start up with, I'm not sure how to do this, but it might be the best option(?).
3. There might be something you can do with web deploy, for example telling it to set web.config values when it runs, but I don't know if this is possible(?).

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the third option is actually possible, what I've done is the following:

Create a `parameters.xml` file in the root of the web application project that contains the parameters I want to change:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Environment"
    description="Please provide the environment name for the application."
    defaultValue="Development"
    tags="">
    <parameterEntry
      kind="XmlFile"
      scope="\\web.config$"
      match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='Environment']/@value" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

This will create a `SetParameters.xml` in the same place as your deployment package when it is created.

You can update the `SetParameters.xml` with the value of the environment you want to deploy to when your deploy step is running, for example in msbuild this would look like this:

```
<XmlUpdate
  XmlFileName="$(DeployFolder)\Project.SetParameters.xml"
  Xpath="/parameters/setParameter[@name='Environment']/@value"
  Value="$(Environment)" />
```

Now you can run your `deploy.cmd` and it'll set the parameters when it deploys on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying multiple instances to the same machine, then I assume the file paths could be helpful?  e.g. deploy to a file path with environment name in folder: C:\inetpub\dev
this is probably the simplest approach.

If you go with option 1 I'd use registry over environment variable.

You can also probably look at the target environment in your build script depending on the build server you are using.